# ST_Intersects Fusion Table KML Data doesn't Clip to Rectangle

Tags: google-maps-api-3, spatial, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to have a user-drawn rectangle serve as a query on a google fusion table containing kml polygon data.  The problem is that the map displays the entire extent of any polygon found within the rectangle's bounds, and does not clip these polygons to the rectangle extent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```js
layerZoom = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: tableid1,
            where: "ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(" + sw.lat() + "," + sw.lng() + "), LATLNG(" + ne.lat() + "," + ne.lng() + ")))"
        }
```

Comment: According to your code you select the whole geometry, you should try to select the intersected polygon only: layerZoom = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ query: { select: "ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(" + sw.lat() + "," + sw.lng() + "), LATLNG(" + ne.lat() + "," + ne.lng() + ")))", from: tableid1, where: "ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(" + sw.lat() + "," + sw.lng() + "), LATLNG(" + ne.lat() + "," + ne.lng() + ")))" }

Comment: Unfortunately, Odi, your suggestion did not work for me.  My query is still showing the portions of the polygons that fall outside of the rectangle bounds too.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Ah yeah sure. ST_INTERSECTS simply returns the original polygons that intersects with the rectagle. Sorry for that. I guess you have to create your own polygon overlay, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little on what you mean by creating my own polygon overlay? My data consists of large polygons representing various soil classes over a large area.  But, as I mentioned earlier, I want the user to zoom into a given area and essentially clip out the soil data within the rectangle bounds.  Can this simply not be done in the google maps api? Thanks Odi!